# google play services .apk file memory

Tags: google-play-services

can any buddy help me
I develop an android app
first it has memory of only 632kb .apk file and shows 1.45mb in app manager (after instead in my phone)

but after importing google play services(for ads from admob) my app has memory of 1.78mb of .apk file and it shows 6.05mb in app manager....

I import google play services in such a way that
1. import google play services lib to package explorer
2.in my app (after left click of mouse)-> properties -> android -> add-> google play services-> ok

then

is there any way to reduce memory of app?
  (or)
is there any other way to add ads to my app?
  (or)
is there any way to import google play services?

I need to reduce memory of my app

I really work for it......

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#RestrictingMemory